# Rails 4 Conversation Model JOIN Table with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have a **Conversation** model with

```
recipient_id
sender_id
```

Fetching the current user's conversations looks like

```
conversations = Conversation.where("conversations.sender_id =? OR conversations.recipient_id =?",current_user.id,current_user.id)
```

Let's call **other_user** the user in the conversation who is not the current_user.

Since the current user can either be the sender or the recipient, it's not possible to use a JOIN or Include on the users table to fetch the "other user" involved in the conversation. Thus, rendering the conversations creates a N+1 situation, issuing 1 query for each other user.

Is there a way to fetch the other_user using an includes or a JOIN, with a condition basically saying:

```
if current_user_id == recipient_id JOIN on recipient_id
if current_user_id == sender_id JOIN on sender_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need certain attributes of the other_user, such as the username, then something like this should work:

```
conversations = Conversation.find_by_sql([<<-SQL, current_user.id, current_user.id, current_user.id])
  SELECT
    convos_involving_user.*
  FROM
    -- We'll use UNION to create a table that joins together the users and
    -- conversations tables based on both sender and recipient. Each
    -- conversation will be represented by two rows in this joined table:
    -- one row joining that conversation to the sender's user info, another
    -- row joining that conversation to the recipient's user info.
    (
    -- join conversations and users based on sender
    SELECT
      conversations.*, users.id AS user_id, users.username AS other_user
    FROM
      conversations
    INNER JOIN
      users ON users.id = conversations.sender_id
    UNION
    -- join conversations and users based on recipient
    SELECT
      conversations.*, users.id AS user_id, users.username AS other_user
    FROM
      conversations
    INNER JOIN
      users ON users.id = conversations.recipient_id
    ) AS convos_involving_user
  -- Now that we conceptually have that big join table with two rows for
  -- each conversation, we filter that table. First, we are only interested
  -- in the conversations where either the recipient or sender is the
  -- current user. But we still have duplicate rows for each message, so we
  -- also filter out the rows that join a conversation rows to the
  -- current_user's row. This leaves, for each conversation involving the
  -- current user, the row that links the conversation to the other user.
  WHERE
    (recipient_id = ? OR sender_id = ?) AND user_id != ?
SQL
```

Then each of the `conversations` will have an `other_user` method that you can call on it to get the username of the other user. You can use this in your view or whatnot. To illustrate using the `other_user` method:

```
conversations.each { |convo| puts convo.other_user }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very interesting and helpful, I still need to improve my SQL so your comments where much needed. Since I fetch conversations with paging (in batches of 10), how does that big join performs compared to the 1 + 10 requests? I tried running it in the console and that seems pretty slow...but still testing it.

Comment: On my machine, in the Rails console, with a database setup with 10,000 users and 100,000 messages randomly between them, it takes about 20ms to run this query the first time, and about 3ms to run the query subsequent times, even for different users, presumably due to caching of some sort. That seems like entirely adequate performance to me. Make sure that you have indexes on `recipient_id` and `sender_id`. Here is the benchmark I used https://gist.github.com/davidrunger/4e726ea780ad1830d4f7.